# Make count if or any other alternative to make it work faster

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have some larger files I need to count the data  and formula I am using `IFERROR(COUNTIFS(ny_rp_sit_1!$A:$A,$A2,ny_rp_sit_1!P:P, "outside of double timeframe"), "Other")`
, But the formula is executing but it is the most time consuming, Is there is any other way to count So that it can work faster

Comment: Anything on this still struggling

Comment: With `Excel2010` faster method will be VBA procedure. If you had `Excel365` then there were some great formula to make it faster.

Comment: is the speed the same if you use `countif()` ?

Comment: yes speed is the same with large files